# sp_send_dbmail sproc: Multiple " From address"

Tags: sql-server, database, email, stored-procedures

I am using SQL Sever 2012. Is it possible to adjust the `FROM_ADDRESS` in `sp_send_dbmail`, depending on who I am sending the email to?

One group of people would receive an email from email address A, another group of people would receive an email from email address B... but both from the same DB?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can use different profiles yes. Just pass the appropriate value to the profile parameter for `sp_send_dbmail`.

Comment: EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
    @profile_name = 'Adventure Works Administrator',  
so  you would just change profile_name?

Comment: *"so you would just change profile_name"* yes.

Comment: you would require more than one profile set up in the DB?...how do you do that?

Comment: Profiles aren't set up in the database, they are set up at the server. [Create a Database Mail Profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/database-mail/create-a-database-mail-profile?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Interesting, so multiple profiles can be set up ...and we just change the variable to instruct which one we want sp_send_dbmail to send from...is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.